# PyQt5 with multiple intents ( pages in the same window )

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm totally new to **PyQt5** and I'm trying to develop an application with a main menu and sub menus and i don't know how to start. All examples that I found are using that pop up windows as sub menu.

Here is an example of what I'm going to do. Any suggestion on how to start and what to use in PyQt5 please ?

[image]

The main menu is on the right and a sub menu is on the left

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: better explains what is shown in the image, nothing is understood.

Comment: each window could be a `QWidget` that you `show()`. For the grid you could use a `QGridlayout` with 6 `QPushbutton`s

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, the main menu can take you to other page.. for example is you press settings button ( shown in the menu ) the current page will be settings page and if you press the wifi button the current page will be wifi page etc ... it's like phone menu simply

Comment: @codingstate okay, if you are on the wifi page, how do you go back to the main menu?

Comment: @eyllanesc in  every page there is "back" button that takes you to the main menu

Comment: @jonas it is working ? simply it's like a phone menu and i need it to be all shown in the same window ( no popup windows )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the main menu you can use `QListWidget` in the icon mode, and to exchange the pages you can use `QStackedLayout`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Page(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, content, parent=None):
        super(Page, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Back")
        button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(content)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.stacked = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        lay.addWidget(self.stacked)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.listWidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onItemClicked)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        for icon, content in [("alarms.png", QtWidgets.QTextEdit() ),
                              ("fitness.png", QtWidgets.QMdiArea() ),
                              ("navigation.png", QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 4) ),
                              ("notifications.png", QtWidgets.QListWidget() )]:

            p = Page(content)
            p.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0))
            self.addPage(QtGui.QIcon(icon), p)

    def addPage(self, icon, widget):
        it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        it.setIcon(icon)
        self.listWidget.addItem(it)
        self.stacked.addWidget(widget)
        it.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole, self.listWidget.count())

    def onItemClicked(self, it):
        ix = it.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        self.stacked.setCurrentIndex(ix)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```